# Exporar ArrayList de una activity a otra

Tags: java, android

Tengo un ArrayList llamado "respuestas" en una activity. Y quiero que, cuando en una activity donde hay creada una encuesta, se responda determinada pregunta, añada la respuesta, que está en cadena string, al array "respuestas". Pero no puedo porque el array no está creado en el activity de la encuesta. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

Buenas compañero @Pablo Gonzalez, si lo que quieres es pasar un array de strings puede usar el siguiente fragmento de ejemplo de código:

Esto ira en tu clase principal de actividad:

```
String[] array1={"asd","fgh","dcf","dg","ere","dsf"};
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
i.putExtra("key",array1);
startActivity(i);
```

Y lo recibirías con lo siguiente en tu otra actividad:

```
String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key");
```

Te dejo el enlace de donde puede ver su versión en ingles, un saludo.

[How to pass a string array value](http://how-to-pass-a-string-array-value-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-androi)

Comment: Gracias, y que puedo hacer para asignar ese array a un ListView, o a un TextView?